# fusebox5 noxml Parsed file 'app.deleterecord.cfm' changed or did not exist

Tags: coldfusion, fusebox

I have a code below

```
<cffunction name="DeleteRecord">
    <cfargument name="myFusebox" />
    <cfargument name="event" />

    <cfset event.xfa("ShowForm", "app.ShowForm") />
    <cfset event.xfa("AddNew", "app.AddNew") />
    <cfset event.xfa("EditRecord", "app.EditRecord") />
    <cfset event.xfa("DeleteRecord", "app.DeleteRecord") />
    <cfset event.xfa("UpdateRecord", "app.UpdateRecord") />

    <cfset DeleteForecastRecord = application.report.ForecastRecordDelete(event.getValue("id"))/>

    <cflocation url="#myFusebox.getMyself()##event.xfa('manageforecastreport')#" addtoken="false" />

</cffunction>
```

and in my cfc file below

```
<!--- ::::: Forecast Record Show ::::: --->
<cffunction name="ForecastRecordShow" returntype="query" access="public" output="true" hint="Add Forecast Record">
    <cfargument name="ForecastID" type="any" default="">
    <cfquery name="qryGetForcastRecord" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
        SELECT * FROM tbl_forecast  
        WHERE ForecastID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#trim(arguments.ForecastID)#">
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn qryGetForcastRecord>
</cffunction>
```

i have an error

> Parsed file 'app.deleterecord.cfm' changed or did not exist
>   Request failed with exception 'Application' (The method ForecastRecordDelete was not found in component C:\Websites\LiquidMetalWheel.com\DiscountTire_dev\model\report.cfc.)
>   The method ForecastRecordDelete was not found in component C:\Websites\mysite.com\model\report.cfc.

Please help me about what can i do to solve this error

Comment: From your error looks like you have a bit of the problem with `report` component: ColdFusion cannot find the method `ForecastRecordDelete`. Since your website and CFC paths are different you could use wrong CFC here, try to dump `application.report` and see what methods are available. `OR` if that is *whole* CFC above -- you don't have a needed method there.

Comment: @Sergii Dear i already check the application using dump function show in tree but when i use this application.report.ForecastRecordDelete but still have error. Even i also create another cfc CURD and it also show in the application tree using dump but still the system generate same error.

Comment: You should check methods available in component, not its availability in the application scope. Your error clearly says: `there is not such method in the component`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "mode" is set to dev and not to prod (prod I think). When set to prod it will assume the file in the parsed directory is the correct one. When set to dev it "reparses" all your fuses with each request.

The "mode" setting is buried in your fusebox setttings - check the fbx_settings.cfm file. I'm doing this from memory so I might be wrong about the *name* of the setting (maybe appsettingStyle or something like that).